# Getting an image/logo to appear in a php email

Tags: php, image, email

I am trying to add my companies logo inside of a php email that I will be sending out to customers after they order. However, it is not working. The actual link to my image is a public url.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    $logoImage = 'https://example.com/images/BFBlogo1.gif';     

// Prepare the Email
$to = $email;
$subject = 'Your Example order'.  $AuthorrizeResponseText;  transaction Id or invoice #, however you set it up as.
$message = '<img src="'.$logoImage.'">';
$message = 'Thank you for ordering with us! ';
$from = "auto-confirm@example.com";
$cc = "order-receipts@example.com";

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: ' .$to. "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' .$from. "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: '.$cc. "\r\n";

// Send the email
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

My second attempt:

```
$message = '<img src="'.$logoImage.'">';
$message .= 'Thank you for ordering with us! ';
```

Comment: Email clients strip out images as they can be used to track users. Specifically spammers used to use them to confirm email accounts were valid. If you want that image to display you need to base64 encode it and place it directly in the HTML.

Comment: How could I do that? Do you have any good tutorials?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to concate:

```
$message = '<img src="'.$logoImage.'">';
$message = 'Thank you for ordering with us! '; // here $message is overwrtting.
```

Should be like this:

```
$message = '<img src="'.$logoImage.'">';
$message .= 'Thank you for ordering with us! ';
```

**Update**

```
logoImage = 'https://example.com/images/BFBlogo1.gif';     

// Prepare the Email
$to = $email;
$subject = 'Your Example order'.  $AuthorrizeResponseText;    
$message = '<img src="'.$logoImage.'">';
$message .= 'Thank you for ordering with us! ';
$from = "auto-confirm@example.com";
$cc = "order-receipts@example.com";

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: ' .$to. "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' .$from. "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: '.$cc. "\r\n";

// Send the email
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: When I concatenate like that I am getting a parse error

Comment: add your error line number. I think you are getting parse error in the `$subject` line.

Comment: Nope it is coming from the second $message line. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in /home4/pfarley1/public_html/orderhandler.php on line 199

Comment: I edited my question and put my current code for those two lines it it

Comment: are you sure line #199 is `$message .= 'Thank you for ordering with us! ';` ?

Comment: Yes. I am sure, the line count is showing 199 right next to that line.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I had when I posted the question? I don't see what you changed other than taking out the concatenate in the second $message?

Comment: did you try it? I have removed comment line in the `$subject`

Comment: Didn't work. In my actual code I had that commented out.. which I still removed on my code. There is not a parse error anymore, but my image is not sending in the email. It is doing just what it was when I made the question.

Comment: `var_dump($message);` before sending email and check if it contains right html.

Comment: Nothing is dumping. I added the var_dump like right before my send the email comment and then right after the line of code to the send the email in a second attempt

Answer (score 0):

You set the image tag:

```
$message = '<img src="'.$logoImage.'">';
```

But then on the very next line you overwrite it:

```
$message = 'Thank you for ordering with us! ';
```

Maybe you meant to concatenate instead?:

```
$message .= 'Thank you for ordering with us! ';
```

Please note also that if nearly the *entire* body of the message is an image then I wouldn't be at all surprised if the mail is treated as spam by almost any system that looks at it.

Comment: I get a syntax error when putting the . after the $message variable. Not sure why